# How to put multiple values in Map from a list

Tags: java, collections

I have a list `gotitems`.

```
ArrayList<String> gotitems = new ArrayList<String>();
```

i need to put that list in a hashmap called `map`.

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
```

i had tried this :

```
for(String s:gotitems){
     map.put("a",s);
}
```

gotitems contains :

```
First
Second
Third
```

But the output of :

```
System.out.println(map.values());
```

gives :

```
Third
Third
Third
```

i had even tried this :

```
for(String s:gotitems){
    for(int j=0;j<gotitems.size();j++){
          map.put("a"+j,s);
    }
}
```

but this is also not working.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: You are putting  a value with same key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Map put(K,V) method docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29)

> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map (optional operation). If the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced by the specified value.

You are ovverriding the key each time here .

```
 for(String s:gotitems){
         map.put("a",s);
    }
```

change the key each time and try like

```
for(String s:gotitems){
     map.put(s,s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are putting all the items in the map against the same key "a"

```
map.put("a");
```

You need to store each element against a unique key so add something like this:

```
int count = 0;
for(String s:gotitems){
     map.put("a" + count,s);
     count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to put three Strings in the map under the same key `"a"`. Try to use unique keys for your values.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting all your items in the `Map` with the same key: "a". 
You should have a unique `String` key for each value.

For instance:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
for (String s: list) {
    map.put(s, s);
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{one=one, two=two, three=three}
```

Note the `LinkedHashMap` here: it maintains the order in which you put your key/value pairs.

**Edit** Of course if your `List` does not have unique values, moving its values as keys to a `Map` will overwrite some of the `Map`'s values. In that case you want to ensure your `List` has unique keys first, or maybe use a `Map<Integer, String>` with the index of the `List`'s value as key to the `Map`, and the actual `List` value as value to the `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write

```
for(String s:gotitems){
     map.put("a",s);
}
```

you will trash any existing entry in the map held against the key "a". So after your iteration, your map will contain just one entry corresponding to the last iterated value in `gotitems`.

To use a map effectively you need to consider what your keys will be. Then use `map.put(myKeyForThisItem, s)` instead. If you don't have an effective scheme for the keys then using a map is pointless as one tends to use the keys to extract the corresponding values.

As for your second approach, it would be helpful if you could define "it is not working" a little clearer: perhaps iterate through the map and print the keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that in a map, a key can point to at most one value. In your case, you are doing the following mappings:
"a" -> "one"
then you overwrite it as
"a" -> "two"
then you overwrite it as
"a" -> "three"

remember: a key can point to at most one value. However, a value can be pointed at by multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
for(String s:gotitems){
     map.put("a",s);
}
```

Since you are using `"a"` common key for all values, last inserted key-value pair would be preserved, all previous ones would be overridden.

This is also not correct:

```
for(String s:gotitems){
    for(int j=0;j<gotitems.size();j++){
          map.put("a"+j,s);
    }
}
```

you are putting n*n times into map, though you want only n (`gotitems.size()`) items into map.

First decide on key which you want to use in map, copying `List` into `Map` one approach could be use index as `key`:

```
for(int j=0;j<gotitems.size();j++){
              map.put("KEY-"+j,gotitems.get(j));
        }
```

Output should be:

> KEY-0 First
>
> KEY-1 Second
>
> KEY-2 Third

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduce your codes. The problem is that you are assigning the same key to different value. This should work.

```
import java.util.*;

public class testCollection{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> gotitems = new ArrayList<String>();
        gotitems.add("First");
        gotitems.add("Second");
        gotitems.add("Third");

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

        String x = "a";
        int i = 1;

        for(String s:gotitems){         
            map.put(x+i,s);
            i++;
        }

        System.out.println(map);
    }   
}
```